# How to create a csv file using python's csv module?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

How can I use python to create a csv file named ted.csv for instance using the csv module:

```
import csv
with open('ted.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
```

Gives me an error

> Module has no attribute reader

Comment: Just `open` the file with `w` mode.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example is seen [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer). You import the csv module. You then open the csv file that you want to write to. When you writerow, you write the data in the array that delimited by the character specified in the delimeter argument to csv.writer.

```
import csv
with open('ted.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

This will give you a ted.csv file with the following content in the file

```
Spam,Spam,Spam,Spam,Spam,Baked Beans
Spam,Lovely Spam,Wonderful Spam
```

Comment: You probably just want `w` mode, not `wb`, since `wb` is binary writing mode, and CSV is a text format.

Comment: You are correct. Though wb should be fine for system other than windows I think. The example was taken from the python docs and simplified a bit.